# how to use same column names with different data types in subquery in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, casting

I have a query:

```
select * 
from proformaentry 
where cast(tcmno as varchar) not in(
    select tcmno from contreceipt
)
```

I want to list all `tcmno` from `proformaentry` table which is not in the table `contreceipt`. In `proformaentry` table, `tcmno` is `int` datatype but in `contreceipt`, it is `varchar` type. So I used above query, but it is not returning any rows.

Actually there are some `tcmno` in `proformaentry` table which is not present in `contreceipt`.

Hope I can get the correct query to retrieve the rows from here.

Comment: Is `contreceipt.tcmno` nullable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing `contrecipt.tcmo` is `NULLABLE`. `NOT IN` clause is the same as nested `AND <>` clauses. Example:

```
declare @tbl table(n int)
insert into @tbl values (1), (2), (3)

select * from @tbl where not n in(4, 5, 6, null)
```

The above query will not return any rows. If you transform the `NOT IN`, it'll be:

```
select * from @tbl where n <> 4 and n <> 5 and n <> 6 and n <> null
```

And since `n <> null` is `FALSE`, *for the purpose of a `WHERE` clause*, the `NOT IN` resulted to `FALSE`. In order to achieve the desired result, you can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select * 
from proformaentry p 
where not exists(
    select 1 from contreceipt where tcmno = cast(p.tcmno as varchar(20))
)
```